# Can I mount another route handler through __meteor_bootstrap__.app?

Tags: meteor

I'm building my first meteor app and need to be able to create a new route handler to handle an oauth callback. I've looked through server.js and found that the connect.app context is available under **meteor_bootstrap**. Although this doesn't seem to work:

```
if (Meteor.is_server) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var app = __meteor_bootstrap__.app;
    app.use('/callback',function (req,res) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end();
      return;
    });
  });
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with this solution is that your middleware is put at the bottom of the stack. Therefore the catch-all meteor handler will always run before your "/callback"-handler.

One very hacky way to get around this (until the meteor releases their proper routing support) is to splice in your handler att the top of the stack:

```
__meteor_bootstrap__.app.stack.splice (0, 0, {
    route: '/hello',
    handle: function (req,res, next) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end("hello world");
        return;
    }.future ()
});
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary after the following change: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/a2d5bfa6dbbecff94877142a57bb212aa7f2a590

Comment: +1 for noticing this and also for the Meteor code change. Can you clarify how that helps, though?

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this with the [Meteor Router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router#server-side-routing) smart package:

```
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/callback': 404
})
```

Comment: This is currently the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the answers are leading to routing being a no-go on the server right now without being hacky. It's a known issue, and sounds like routing is a hot item on the todo list.