# How do you make a REST API and upload files in Meteor

Tags: rest, meteor

What is about a REST API? Is there already a way to define some routes and logic for the API on the server? I think this is nowadays a must-have feature.

And the same with File-Uploads. With express framework I can already handle uploads really easy. How do I do this in Meteor? The documentation says nothing about it. So are there some plans to implement it? Or is there already a way?

Comment: The "REST API" part is a duplicate of [How to expose a RESTful web service using Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150538/how-to-expose-a-restful-web-service-using-meteor), which has far better answers.

Answer (score 9):

As far as [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) goes: Meteor doesn't yet provide a supported API for serving HTTP from your application. This is intentional: in the not-too-distant future, your application server is likely to not be just a single process directly serving end users, but an arbitrarily parallelizable service behind a proxy tier. So we'll need to provide a supported API for responded to HTTP requests (for example, REST) that continues to work in such a setting.

If you really need to accept direct HTTP REST requests now, take a peek at how `packages/accounts-oauth-helper/oauth_server.js` uses `__meteor_bootstrap__.app` to hook into the Connect middleware framework. This will work for now, but we don't promise that Meteor will always be powered by Connect :)

Supporting REST endpoints is on [Meteor's roadmap](https://trello.com/card/page-model-server-side-rendering-rest-endpoints/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/7).

So is file uploads (that's what [binary type](https://trello.com/card/official-ddp-specification/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/53) refers to).

Comment: Another example of setting up HTTP endpoints can be found in Tom Coleman's meteor-router package. https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router/blob/master/router_server.js#L151

Comment: The "REST API" part is a duplicate of [How to expose a RESTful web service using Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150538/how-to-expose-a-restful-web-service-using-meteor), which has updated answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using 
https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi#readme

Which will create rest endpoints on your collections right out of the box. You can use meteorite to install it.

Comment: The "REST API" part is a duplicate of [How to expose a RESTful web service using Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150538/how-to-expose-a-restful-web-service-using-meteor), which has updated answers.