# how to create a Rest API in Meteor

Tags: api, rest, meteor

How can one design/write an efficient rest API with meteor, that can also be used by mobile apps? Can mobile apps also take advantage of meteors reactive programming?

With so many programming choices currently available, it seems wasteful to repeat everything(code, api) for different platforms, instead of having a good practical solution.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150538/how-to-expose-a-restful-web-service-using-meteor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your post is really two different questions.

1. Yes, there is a way to attach REST endpoints to Meteor. You just write them as normal Node.js code using connect or Express and attach them to the `WebApp.connectHandlers` after pulling in the `webapp` package (`meteor add webapp`).
2. Mobile apps can take advantage of reactivity by being implemented in Javascript. You can either access your app directly from a mobile browser, or just use PhoneGap/Cordova to wrap it in a "native" app container. As phones become more popular, this will probably be the default way to deploy apps versus writing many copies of the same app in different codebases.

Comment: My need for exposing REST endpoints to the meteor app was for the mobile apps to be able to call it. That was at least my backend and logic would be isolated in one place.

Also I had disregarded PhoneGap due to really bad compatibility and maintenance reviews.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your first question, I published a package for writing REST APIs in Meteor 0.9+. The APIs can certainly be consumed by mobile apps:

https://github.com/krose72205/meteor-restivus

It was inspired by [RestStop2](http://github.differential.com/reststop2/) and built with [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router)'s server-side routing.

**UPDATE:** I just wanted to include a code example for anyone that finds this. This is the Restivus Quick Start example from the GitHub README:

```
Items = new Mongo.Collection 'items'

if Meteor.isServer

  # Global API configuration
  Restivus.configure
    useAuth: true
    prettyJson: true

  # Generates: GET, POST, DELETE on /api/items and GET, PUT, DELETE on
  # /api/items/:id for Items collection
  Restivus.addCollection Items

  # Generates: GET, POST on /api/users and GET, DELETE /api/users/:id for
  # Meteor.users collection
  Restivus.addCollection Meteor.users,
    excludedEndpoints: ['deleteAll', 'put']
    routeOptions:
      authRequired: true
    endpoints:
      post:
        authRequired: false
      delete:
        roleRequired: 'admin'

  # Maps to: /api/posts/:id
  Restivus.addRoute 'posts/:id', authRequired: true,
    get: ->
      post = Posts.findOne @urlParams.id
      if post
        status: 'success', data: post
      else
        statusCode: 404
        body: status: 'fail', message: 'Post not found'
    post:
      roleRequired: ['author', 'admin']
      action: ->
        post = Posts.findOne @urlParams.id
        if post
          status: "success", data: post
        else
          statusCode: 400
          body: status: "fail", message: "Unable to add post"
    delete:
      roleRequired: 'admin'
      action: ->
        if Posts.remove @urlParams.id
          status: "success", data: message: "Item removed"
        else
          statusCode: 404
          body: status: "fail", message: "Item not found"
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the mobile part of your question,

Meteor will integrate a packaging process to release your app as an iOS / Android app by the use of Cordova. You may want to check this video out : [Meteor Devshop SF August 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzNoXbv1DX4&feature=youtu.be&t=24m), it's a presentation of said Meteor features with live demo.

It is true that you will never come close to the raw performance of Native application, but maintenance costs and skill set required by developers on your project are nowhere near comparable either.

For the API part, it is possible to produce RESTful API with Meteor. Using [iron-router severside routing](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#server-side-routing) is a possible option.

The **Full Edition** of the [Discover Meteor Book](https://www.discovermeteor.com/) has an *Extra chapter* dedicated to just that.

Comment: Thanks thats awesome. Look forward to a cordova package compatible with Meteor 0.9 to try.