# Mobile Apps with AngularJS and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

What is the best way to create mobile apps for Android/iOS using AngularJS for the frontend and C# ASP.NET for the backend? The app I want to build is going to make heave use of databases (not sure which kind of database yet).

I've been looking at Xamarin, Apache Cordova and Phonegap but I don't quite understand where the difference between those are and if C# ASP.NET can be used for the backend. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin uses c# as programming language, so you can create your code once and then build native apps for IOS and Android without repeating yourself.

if you plan to use angularJs for your mobile app I'd recommend you to stick to [ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/) it's optimized for mobile development and relies on Javascript, CSS and HTML.

from the architecture perspective I'd recommend to you to use an API first approach, take a look to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963676/advantages-of-a-separate-rest-backend-api/27964773#27964773) for a broader picture.

so your combination could be:

- Database or NoSQL for persistence (backend)
- C# web API (middleware)
- AngularJS in frontend (frontend web)
- IonicFramework for Mobile (frontend mobile)

I hope that helps.