# How should I run a REST API with Meteor?

Tags: node.js, express, meteor

I need the Meteor server to handle a very simple POST request not coming from the application client. With Express, I'd just do something like `app.post('/something', function...`.

Is there an equivalent in Meteor? If not, how should I set this up, startup an Express server in a `is_server` context?

Comment: Just checked in IRC (#meteor on irc.freenode.net) and was told that this is simply not implemented (yet).

Comment: it doesn't provide because Meteor isn't designed to work that way. The docs tell it's designed for real time communication, not Rest

Comment: You can run a REST API with Meteor as described at [How to expose a RESTful Web Service using Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150538/howto-expose-a-restful-web-service-using-meteor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meteor does not yet have the built in functionality to provide a restful API.

Comment: Is there anyone working on it? Is there any plans of implementing it?

Comment: Is it impossible to implement given the architecture?

Comment: @lefnire: REST support can be implemented with Meteor - see [Can I mount another route handler through __meteor_bootstrap__.app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119777/can-i-mount-another-route-handler-through-meteor-bootstrap-app). Greg: Any chance to update your answer?

Comment: There is now another option: [meteor-collectionapi](https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi), see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can build basic routing into our application using Backbone, as in the Meteor example provided here: http://meteor.com/examples/todos

You can do something like this:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "": "dashboard",
    "home": "dashboard",
    "profile": "profile",
},

profile: function () {
    Session.set("current_view", "profile")
    this.navigate('profile', {trigger: true});
},
```

Also take a look at: [How to expose a RESTful Web Service using Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150538/howto-expose-a-restful-web-service-using-meteor)

Comment: There is a package on atmosphere that does Meteor routing - https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/router

Comment: I noticed they just released it  a few days ago - looks like exactly what I accomplished with Backbone! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can serve RESTful APIs with Meteor using the [meteor-collectionapi](https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi) Atmosphere package. See also [Is Meteor an option, if i need an additional REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11167874/396967).