# Meteor.js apps and API's

Tags: rest, express, sinatra, meteor

I'm trying to work out if Meteor.js is a good fit for an app I would like to build.

The app will be completely web based but will require me to implement a RESTful API that exposes some of its functionality.

Is this doable with Meteor.js or would something like Express/Sinatra be better suited?

Answer (score 6):

It is now doable with Meteor using the [meteor-collectionapi](https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi) Atmosphere package. See also [Is Meteor an option, if i need an additional REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11167874/396967).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on where your comfort levels are with what you want to build on as a framework.

If you're thinking about using Meteor you are able to build a REST api by using a package on the [atmosphere](http://atmosphere.meteor.com) repository called [Meteor Router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router). [Meteor Router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) allows you to create server side routes which you can implement REST requests from the server end.

In addition to REST meteor also has another interface called DDP (Distributed Data Protocol), which is similar to REST but attempts to keep an open socket at all times so that data can be pushed either way.

At the moment there are DDP clients for Objective C, NodeJS, Python, .NET & Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely it's doable, I just did it, and I used the [HTTP.publish](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-http-publish) library which elegantly adds HTTP alongside DDP as a protocol for communicating with the database.

Comment: You were using meteor router or iron router ? is there any difference using one or another ?

Comment: @CassioS.Cabral I used the Meteor router.  I haven't tried Iron Router.