# Meteor - render meta tags server side

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I need to have some dynamic meta tags in my page's head that need to be parsed by Facebook, so they have to be generated server-side. Is it doable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate Facebook's Open Graph in a Meteor application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281405/how-to-integrate-facebooks-open-graph-in-a-meteor-application)

Comment: See my answer, here - it helped me solve the exact same problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281405/how-to-integrate-facebooks-open-graph-in-a-meteor-application

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question. The solution is to implement your own server routing. See [How to integrate Facebook's Open Graph in a Meteor application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281405/how-to-integrate-facebooks-open-graph-in-a-meteor-application).

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem with social share on meteor. I wrote this tutorial: https://webdevelopment7636.wordpress.com/2017/02/15/social-share-with-meteor/ . It will show you how to create dynamics meta tags on server side, so it the crawlers will reach.