# Include og: tags in Meteor App

Tags: meteor, facebook-opengraph

I have read [How to integrate Facebook's Open Graph in a Meteor application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281405/how-to-integrate-facebooks-open-graph-in-a-meteor-application) and followed it closely, however, the og tags are still not registered):

I would just like to set several images to ensure that several thumbnails appear when u type http://bubble.meteor.com in facebook

Here are my codes: 
(Updated)

```
<head>
...
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://bubble.meteor.com/img/ogimage1.png">
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://bubble.meteor.com">
  <meta property="og:title" content="Emory Bubble">
</head>
```

Am I doing anything wrongly? Thanks!

Comment: Do i have to register my app in facebook developer to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, an `<html>` tag does not belong inside the `<head>`. Meteor always uses the HTML5 doctype definition. Even if you would manage to change it to XHTML, you will probably end up with invalid XHTML, because extension packages that inject HTML assume HTML5.

Second, there is no need to declare any namespace for the OpenGraph tags. Strings like "og:title" are just opaque data inside a property and they do not affect the HTML parser.

**UPDATE**

I checked it using Facebook's debug page and it does not work indeed: 
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

This yielded an "Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped" error.

I also checked the page using the special escaped fragment URL that should trigger the spiderable package:
http://bubble.meteor.com/?_escaped_fragment_=

The resulting page contains no HTML content and the Javascript tags were still present, suggesting that the spiderable package does not work. Did you add that one to your project? (`meteor add spiderable`).

If you added it, it does not work. The spiderable package returns the normal page if running PhantomJS fails. You should check it on your local development version, use the above URL to trigger spiderable.

I also noticed that you are using 'school' as `og:type`, which is not a valid type as far as I know. Try 'website' instead.

**UPDATE 2**

Also checkout this screencast by Chris Mather about the spiderable package:
http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-the-spiderable-package

In this screencast he mentions a potential problem with subscriptions that are never marked as ready and make the spiderable package fail. Maybe this is causing your issues?

Comment: Hi thanks for answering! In that case, how should i declare the tags such that its registering in Facebook's posts?

Comment: I have added spiderable as shown in the tags when a curl is done. However, the body still does not show any content. This is frustrating): konrad do you know if i have to register my app as a facebook app to get it to work?

Comment: You don't need to register your webpage for this to work. The <meta name="fragment" content="!"> tag is still in the output, which indicates that spiderable has failed and returns the normal page instead, see the source code at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/spiderable/spiderable.js

Comment: Just wondering: can you remove the 'support widget' and try again? Try running it locally and see if you get an error somewhere in your logs: Meteor._debug("spiderable: phantomjs failed:", error, "\nstderr:", stderr)

Comment: Spiderable is not working and I am unsure of the cause of it. I have removed spiderable as it seems to be working against headly package.