# Dynamic Integration of Facebook metatag in meteor

Tags: facebook, coffeescript, meta-tags

I am using a meteor application with Facebook share in CoffeeScript. I had tried manuelschoebel:ms-seo package https://github.com/DerMambo/ms-seo, lookback:seo package https://github.com/lookback/meteor-seo and also reffered [How to integrate Facebook's Open Graph in a Meteor application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281405/how-to-integrate-facebooks-open-graph-in-a-meteor-application) for facebook meta tags to work with iron router.Both packages doesn't work dynamically for me and also I am not getting any errors, The code I used with manuelschoebel:ms-seo package is shown below,

```
@route '/foo/:id',
 name: 'foo'
 controller: 'foobar'
 where: 'client'
 action: 'foo'
 onAfterAction: ->
  obj= Broadcasts.find(
      _id: @params.id
      userId: Meteor.userId()
    ).fetch()
  if obj.length && obj[0].banner
    banner= obj[0].banner
  else
    banner= Meteor.settings.public.s3_url + 'images/foo/default-banner.jpg'
  if obj.length && obj[0].description
    description= obj[0].description
  SEO.config
    og:
      image: banner
      description: description
    fb:
      app_id: Meteor.settings.public.facebook.appId
```

Can anyone please help me to figure out the issue. Thanks in advance